# Help with unzipping a .dd.gz, possibly corrupted

Tags: fedora, mount, partition, dd, zip

I recieved this file that I was told was a copy of a hard drive (or disk). The file is "sheeva-mem.dd.gz". I tried to unzip the file in a linux Fedora machine. This yielded "unexpected end of file". Someone told me to mount the file to a partition within the linux machine, and then I would be able to view the information within the file. I assume the file has to be unzipped before this can happen? If that is the case, is there anyway around the "unexpected end of file" (maybe a repair, or something that ignores the errors)? This is the only copy of the file.

Comment: This error is often caused by a truncated archive. Can you ask someone to send you the file again?

Comment: What makes you think its a zip file?

Comment: No someone cannot resend the file, this is the only copy. And the ".gz" at the end of it makes me think its zipped.

Comment: What's the output of `file XX.dd.gz`

Comment: the output is "sheeva-mem.dd.gz: gzip compressed data, was "sheeva-mem.dd", from Unix, last modified: Fri Sep 14 20:58:18 2012"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `gzrt` (gz repair tool) to unzip whatever part of the dd file remains. You can then type

```
gzrecover sheeva-mem.dd.gz
```

and attempt to mount the dd file:

```
mount sheeva-mem.dd /mnt/image -o loop
```

Possibly, the filesystem will be corrupted. You can attempt to repair it with `fsck`.

Comment: Ok, when I try to run the gzrecover command it says "command not found". Is this a tool that I need to download or should it already be on the system?

Comment: Yes, you need to install this tool. I don't know what your system is, on Debian based systems you can just do `sudo apt-get install gzrt`

Comment: Im running a Fedora 64-bit, and that command does not work. I tried to get the tool the "normal" way (with Yum, how I get all my other stuff), but that didnt work. Do you know where I can get it off the internet, or the command on Fedora? (thx for all your help btw).

Answer (score 0):

gzip != zip.  gzip is a stream compressor, zip is an index'd compressor. They are completely different programs. "zip" is based on "PKzip", and is represented by the tools "unzip" and "zip" and uses ".zip"; GNU zip is "gzip" and "gunzip", uses the extension ".gz".

You can gunzip file.dd.gz and get file.dd, but that'll suck up a lot of space unfortunately.

Once you have the file.dd, just do, probably as root,

mount -o loop file.dd /mnt

to access the contents on /mnt

Answer (score 0):

I've got bunch of corrupted `.gz` files with text files inside, tried to use `unzip -FF` with no success. Surprisingly `7z` managed to extract with no problem, gave me `ERROR: Unexpected end of data` but extracted:

`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

`7z x text.log.gz`